# What meaning "programming API for HTML" in the DOM HTML?

Tags: dom

Anyone could help me to understand this concept basic about DOM fromHTML, I saw in the documentation they say this :

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is a programming API for HTML and XML documents.

For example the API from Google :

[API Google](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/)

But because DOM is an API? 
Anyone could explain because DOM is a API?

This is the article full :

> What is the Document Object Model?
>
> Editors
>
> Jonathan Robie, Texcel Research
>
> Introduction
>
> The Document Object Model (DOM) is a programming API for HTML and XML
>   documents. It defines the logical structure of documents and the way a
>   document is accessed and manipulated. In the DOM specification, the
>   term "document" is used in the broad sense - increasingly, XML is
>   being used as a way of representing many different kinds of
>   information that may be stored in diverse systems, and much of this
>   would traditionally be seen as data rather than as documents.
>   Nevertheless, XML presents this data as documents, and the DOM may be
>   used to manage this data.

From [here in w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the DOM, documents have a logical structure which is very much like a tree; to be more precise, it is like a "forest" or "grove", which can contain more than one tree. However, the DOM does not specify that documents must be implemented as a tree or a grove, nor does it specify how the relationships among objects be implemented. The DOM is a logical model that may be implemented in any convenient manner.

Comment: yes I know that but how working the DOM internally?